# Converting only non utf-8 files to utf-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic, iconv

I have a set of `md` files, some of them are utf-8 encoded, and others are not (`windows-1256` actually).

I want to convert only non-utf-8 files to utf-8.

The following script can *partly* do the job:

```sh
for file in *.md;
do
    iconv -f windows-1256 -t utf-8 "$file" -o "${file%.md}..md";
done
```

I still need to exclude the original utf-8 files from this process, (maybe using `file` command?). Try the following command to understand what I mean:

```sh
file --mime-encoding *
```

Notice that although `file` command isn't smart enough to detect the right character set of non-utf-8 files, It's enough in this case that it can distinguish between utf-8 and non-utf-8 files.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example an `if` statement:

```
if file --mime-encoding "$file" | grep -v -q utf-8 ; then
    iconv -f windows-1256 -t utf-8 "$file" -o "${file%.md}..md";
fi
```

If `grep` doesn't find a match, it returns a status code indicating failure. The `if` statement tests the status code